# Cannot redirect users to ?next page after logged in in Django

Tags: python, django, url, redirect

I'm trying to redirect user back to the *current* page after they're logged in/out with the following template:

> base.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <li>User: {{ user.get_username }}</li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}?next={{request.path}}">Logout</a></li>
{% else %}
  <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

A user logout would be brought to the current page when they logged out, which is expected. However, after they has logged in, they is redirected to `/`, presumably because I've set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to `'/'` in the project's `settings.py`. If I unset `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, they would be brought to `/accounts/profile/`, which is also not what I want.

> Console output:
>
> ```
> [23/Mar/2017 17:23:16] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/catalog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1806
> [23/Mar/2017 17:23:45] "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
> [23/Mar/2017 17:23:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0
> [23/Mar/2017 17:23:45] "GET /catalog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1707
> ```

It seems that the `?next` argument in the URL is not working, and I guess this issue has something to do with the `POST` request.

How do I specify the link to which users are redirected after they've logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `?next=` in the login form action to make it work. Check your form in the login page template.

The `next` is used when login view is requested with `POST` method and is valid.

Your template shoud include something like:

```
{% if next %}
<form action="/login/?next={{next}}" method="post" >
{%else%}
<form action="/login/" method="post" >
{% endif %}
```

Sometimes people put additional hidden field in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="" />
```

Which seems to be your case (in comment you said about tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication ). Then you can instead only change the field to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
```

Since the field from the POST overrides the GET value of the next, even if it is empty, you should use only one of this methods.

Comment: Seems closer, but still not working :-( `[23/Mar/2017 18:30:53] "GET /catalog/books/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1947
[23/Mar/2017 18:30:54] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/catalog/books/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1829
[23/Mar/2017 18:30:55] "POST /accounts/login/?next=/catalog/books/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[23/Mar/2017 18:30:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[23/Mar/2017 18:30:55] "GET /catalog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1707`

Comment: I assume you are using default django login view? Try removing `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`. Also try to run it in a fresh browser (private mode maybe?). It should work with `django.contrib.auth.views.login` (I used it yesterday that way and was OK :) ).

Comment: I've removed the configuration for `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` and opened my site in private mode, only to `Page not found at /accounts/profile/`. This is because I haven't implemented `/accounts/profile/` yet, but I don't want to redirect users to that page anyway...

Comment: And you are using the django original `login` view?

Comment: I'm following [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication) and I guess so... As a beginner, I'm not very sure what "the django original `login` view" refers to, but I can confirm I didn't implement the authentication system myself. All I have done is writing templates.

Comment: OK. Now I see :) Remove `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="" />` from the form or remove `?next=` from action and put into the input value `{{ next }}`. This will fix the issue :) input is overriding the get value of `next` field. Also, please put your link to the tutorial into the question to make it complete, I will edit my answer for future people :)